# Does dynamic quorum having any solution for partition in time?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, sql-server-2019

Assume 2 node 1 file share cluster (Node 1 is active), where say the file share is down for some reason. The dynamic quorum will allow cluster to continue working and assign the voting capability randomly to one of the nodes. Assume the vote is assigned to node 1.

Now assume node 2 goes down, the cluster will still be online. Say a config change is made to node 1 (note that node 2 is down). Then node 1 is shut down.

Now node 2 is started and say the file share is also online. At this point the file share won't have the correct latest config update time, and neither will the node 2 have the updated config.

This will result on partition in time scenario. How is this handled?

Answer (score 0):

> This will result on partition in time scenario

A partition in time or simply a partition will eventually lead to a split brain scenario. Partition here refers to grouping in such a way that the groups cant communicate or do not have clear visibility on status of cluster. Both partitions try to gain control of cluster and with uncertainty leading to split brain and causing cluster to shutdown.

> Now node 2 is started and say the file share is also online. At this point the file share won't have the correct latest config update time.

Why do you think so ? I believe it will come online and will be owner of the resources and this will be aptly managed by WSFC. (Assuming your nodes are in same subnet). Please read [Voting and Non-Voting Nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/wsfc-quorum-modes-and-voting-configuration-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#VotingandNonVotingNodes). Please note FSW is just an additional vote to become a tiebreaker in case both nodes cannot communicate.

Comment: Search for `partition in time` in https://learnsqlserverhadr.com/every-vote-matters-in-your-sql-server-ag/. It is not the same as split brain scenario.

Comment: @variable changed my answer a bit.